# java delta time problems with canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

hi am trying to make a small game using canvas and bitmaps i want my game to run the same on all devices i found delta time is the best practice for this but for some reason when i try to implement it into my code i have display issues for example am trying to move my coluds in the sky but when i add the delta they all disapere i dont know if im doing it wrong so please can sombody help me heres the code

```
private float c1x = 0.0f;
private float c2x = cloudWidth;
private float c3x = cloudWidth * 2;
private float cloudSpeed = 0.1f;
private long curentTime;
private long lastTime = 0;
private double delta;

@Override
public void run(){
    while(running){
        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;
        }

        curentTime = System.nanoTime();
        delta = curentTime - lastTime;
        lastTime = curentTime;

        cloudMovement();

        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bg, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(sun, 20, 20, null);

        canvas.drawBitmap(cloud1, c1x, c1y, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(cloud2, c2x, c2y, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(cloud3, c3x, c3y, null);

        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

}

private void cloudMovement(){

    if(c1x <= 0 - cloudWidth){
        c1x = w;
        c1y = y.nextInt(rand);
    }
    if(c2x <= 0 - cloudWidth){
        c2x = w;
        c2y = y.nextInt(rand);
    }
    if(c3x <= 0 - cloudWidth){
        c3x = w;
        c3y = y.nextInt(rand);
    }
    c1x-=cloudSpeed * delta;
    c2x-=cloudSpeed * delta;
    c3x-=cloudSpeed * delta;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a global FPS mechanism instead which forces a steady FPS on your game :)

If you track the FPS the game will run the same way on any device and you dont need to include delta-times on all update processes.

Here's a code snippet from a FpsTracker i used in an old project:

```
private static final long SECOND = 1000;
private static final long TARGET_FPS = 40;
private static final long FRAME_PERIOD = SECOND / TARGET_FPS;

private long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

/**
 * 
 * @param startTime
 * @return <code>true</code> if the interval between startTime and the time
 *         when this method was called is smaller or equal to the given
 *         frame period.
 * 
 *         Will return <code>false</code> if the interval was longer.
 */
public boolean doFpsCheck(long startTime) {

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= SECOND) {
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    long sleepTime = FRAME_PERIOD
            - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

    if (sleepTime >= 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //TODO handle this properly
            e.printStacktrace()
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If this method returns `false` it means that your operations took longer that the timeperiod you gave to one frame. You can react to this by checking the `doFpsCheck`return parameter.

Implementing this in your code would look like this:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    while(running)
    {
        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
        {
            continue;
        }

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        cloudMovement();

        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bg, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(sun, 20, 20, null);

        canvas.drawBitmap(cloud1, c1x, c1y, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(cloud2, c2x, c2y, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(cloud3, c3x, c3y, null);

        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        doFpsCheck(startTime);
    }

}
```

By the way - it is good practice to devide your game loop into pro sub processes, one being the update process, the other being the draw process.
For many different Bitmaps you should consider extracting the fields and functionalities into seperate classes containing a `draw(Canvas c)` and `update()` method. So you wont get a trillion fields on your main class.

Comment: hello thank you for the response everything seems good i just have a question about the veriable "frame" you have it incrementing but i cant tell where it comes from or how it is used and also is it going to increment indefinatly or is it supose to be reset please can you explain it

Comment: @user2692997 hey dont worry about that, was a code fragment i forgot to delete for this example (the original code way way bigger ;-))

Comment: looks like everything is working fine thank you very much for all your help